# Excel-Need to tweak function to find exact cell matches matches

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup

I have a data set of items with their corresponding categories. Columns A and B are non-essential to this, but the rows need to correspond to column C. Column C is the item category, 40,000 items.
In Column E I have a set of numbers corresponding to a list of Category names in Column G, which are both 780 items long.

I would like to search through column C for the category in the list (Column E), and end up with the number of that category (Column D Value) corresponding to every item in the data set (temporarily column F). I will copy them to column C when I'm done and delete columns D-F.

The Formula I have now is **=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH($E$2:$E$780,C2),$D$2:$D$780).**

The problem is that there are words like "Spray Equipment Turbines" and then words like "Spray" and it chooses Spray first and assigns the wrong number. I need to **match case and the entire cell contents**. I tried doing find & replace but quit after doing 80 of the 780 and wasting too much time.

I have been trying to get vlookup to work but I keep on getting #N/A, #Value, and #Ref. Sometimes all at the same time. Also looked into making a macro for the find and replace because it has the specificity I need, but that's a little above my abilities. I know I'm missing something really basic, but I haven't had any luck finding a solution online and appreciate any help. Thanks.

P.S. Could someone explain what the 2,1/ is in my function so I can edit it in the future, I get the other operating logic but have no idea what those are derived from.

I also really appreciate this community for being so helpful! I feel more comfortable with Excel thanks to you, but some basics still snag me. Vlookup doesn't like me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>I need to **match case and the entire cell contents**.</sub>

There seems to be some contradictions between your narrative and the sample formula as to whether column G or column D contains the desired output. I'll use column D.

Try this in the 2nd row of an unused column and fill down.

```
=index(d:d, aggregate(15, 7, row($2:$780)/exact(e$2:e$780,C2), 1))
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. Sorry for the confusion, you were right to use column D.